# Firestore snapshot listener limit in node.js application

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nodejs backend that is serving as a gRPC server in front of a cloud firestore datastore. In perusing the [best practices documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates) for Firestore, I noticed: "limit snapshot listeners to 100 per client".

This is a pretty reasonable limitation if a "client" is a web UI or flutter application, but does the same limitation apply to a node.js or golang server connecting to the database via the admin interface? Suddenly, in the best case I am looking at 100 concurrent users per server process, which isn't super-great, if those users each request a single resource in streaming mode.

So: does that 100 snapshot listeners per client limitation apply when the "client" is actually a backend API service? And if so, what are some best practices to work around this?

(yes, I know I could just use the regular client API in the client itself, and will be doing that, I am mostly wondering about the limitations in an academic sense, as I was considering using streaming GRPC because there's a fair bit of data massaging that needs to happen between the storage representation and what the client consumes, so putting that all into a single place on a server where I control the rollout frequency is easier than dealing with data representation sync errors because some client is using an older implementation of a transformer method. Plus: that's extra data / code to ship to clients).

Answer (score 3):

The 100 snapshot listeners per client limit should apply for any client, including a backend API service.

Firestore doesn't have a way to make the distinction on where the calls come from, and as such there's no built-in mechanism to make it to exempt the limitation.

Comment: Huh, so this basically eliminates the use of a listener-driven service which could transform data between storage can client, unless you can afford to scale out one task per 100 clients in some reasonable way.

Kind of a bummer - I like the rapid development firestore provides, but unless I can but a circuit breaker between my data and presentation layers, I end up having to severely overindex display to data structure.